# Adjusting dates to avoid overlap of days

Tags: arrays, r, days

If I have three dates, e.g. `Jan 1`, `Jan 25`, and `Feb 20` but I want the dates to be separated by `30 days`, how can i do it?
For example, what I want to do is `Jan 1`, `Jan 30`, `Feb 29`.

I am very new at R but the code should be something like this - If `2nd date` is before (`1st date`+30), then adjust `2nd date` to (`1st`+31) and similarly for `3rd date.`.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What happened when you tried what you suggested in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a fixed distance between each adjacent pair of dates, you don't need to "adjust" any dates; rather, you can just compute the desired date vector from scratch, starting with the first date.

This can actually be done with a single call to the S3 generic [`seq()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html), which will dispatch to [`seq.Date()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.Date.html):

```
seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),by=30,length.out=3);
## [1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-31" "2000-03-01"
```

Also note that you seem to have made an error in deriving your expected dates; 30 days from Jan 1 is Jan 31, not Jan 30.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually wanted to count Jan 1 as the first day..hence I mentioned Jan 30..

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = as.Date("01-01",format="%m-%d")
d2 = as.Date("01-25",format="%m-%d")
if (abs(as.numeric(difftime(d2,d1)))<30) d2 = d1 + 30

>d2
[1] "2015-01-31"
```